# Stress testing all SATA links

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sata

I have a few servers. Each has 9 backplanes, and each backplane has 5 hard drives. Once in a while, one of the cables connecting a backplane to the motherboard (actually a pci card on the motherboard) fails, and the system starts throwing errors, and keeps resetting the SATA link. But this happens only when there is a lot of load on a particular link. Replacing the cable sets everything alright.

My question is, is there a tool (for Linux) that can stress test all the SATA links, so that I can know which cable is faulty before deploying a server for production? Something that writes excessively to all the hard drives? (Note: hard drives are raided in groups of 15, and then a logical volume is made out of the 3 raid sets. When I try writing a lot of data to the volume, the OS usually only writes to one raid array.)

Answer (score 0):

`badblocks` will write to every sector of a drive (random data or zeros, at your choosing) and then reread it to verify.

I'm unclear on how a RAID setup would prevent writing completely to all drives unless your RAID containers are smaller than the capacity of your drives (I'm not terribly experienced with RAID so I may be wrong).  You'd need to undo the RAID configuration and let them be directly addressable individually by Linux to test with `badblocks` fully.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Skipper it sounds like you have a [BackBlaze Pod](http://blog.backblaze.com/2013/02/20/180tb-of-good-vibrations-storage-pod-3-0/) <=3.0 and you are trying to check the SATA link to the port multiplier (and possibly also from the multiplier to the attached drives.

Comment: How it answers the question?could u elaborate your answer?

Comment: It does not answer the question it may clarify it somewhat. I did a minute search on google and found nothing immediately related to what I think the question is. which means one of the following nobody knows anything useful, somebody knows but is not posting about it or most likely I am too thick to ask the right question.

Comment: I remember seeing the blog entry I linked above mentioned issues with flaky connectors on SATA cables and I thought they might liaise.
My wrong headed idea that the SATA is essentially a special type of computer network and what would probably work best is something
almost but not completely unlike the hash column of a rainbow table fed into ping -p.